# java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-twitter, bigdata

I am unable to find the HDFS path and save the log files of Twitter. Also it gives two warnings.

```
WARN: HBASE_HOME not found
WARN: HIVE_HOME not found
```

The error is:

> java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs://l27.0.0.1:9000/tweets/movies/2016/01/29/01/FlumeData.1454010974716.tmp

My `core-site.xml` is

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is flume-twitter?

Comment: @TylerH application of flume in twitter

Comment: Might be related: the error message has 'l' instead '1' in the IP address :)